# Twilio Flex Voicemail Flex Task Assignment Workflow

Tags: twilio

Hello I have a workflow here
It sends callers to a queue with a single worker.
I want to implement voicemail and have followed the instructions here https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021082934-Implementing-Voicemail-with-Twilio-Flex-TaskRouter-and-Insights

If I put the filter first in the workflow then it always goes to voicemail, if next then it never goes.

How can I make it so that if calls are maybe reserved but not answered they go to the voicemail queue?

```
{
  "task_routing": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "filter_friendly_name": "Voicemail ",
        "expression": "1==1",
        "targets": [
          {
            "queue": "theRealqueue",
            "timeout": 10
          },
          {
            "queue": "voicemail",
            "timeout": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "default_filter": {
      "queue": "gfhfghgfhghfghgfhfghgfh"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 problems.
I decided to put in a,
"skip_if": "workers.available == 0" On the first filter and it makes sense now as in the GUI, it is DO NOT SKIP as the default, so to my thinking that means what it says.

And WOW it worked, I had earlier set a TASK RESERVATION TIMEOUT of 8 seconds but when I tried increasing this it never got to voicemail/never went to next step.

I could only get it to work with that 8 second TASK RESERVATION TIMEOUT, not a larger value so then I looked in the Studio Flow,
SEND TO FLEX had a timeout of 10 second, my bad. Increased and all good now.

The documentation/tutorial here is terrible, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021082934-Implementing-Voicemail-with-Twilio-Flex-TaskRouter-and-Insights

4. Select the default Assign to Anyone workflow, or the appropriate workflow if you have modified this.
5. Click Add a Filter.
   Name your Filter Voicemail (or something similarly identifiable), and then change the TIMEOUT to 30 seconds. Click Add a Step when finished.
6. Click the QUEUE value, and then select the Voicemail queue you created in the previous section. Press Save when finished.

That is all not so relevant here, it seems that the thing that controls the going to next step is the TASK RESERVATION TIMEOUT and that no step would be skipped/passed unless a "skip_if": is defined.
I would really love to get clarification on all this.
But the steps that I have done have provided a solution. I banged my head into walls for a few days here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the timeout you have set for each of the targets counts as the time the task spends in that queue regardless of the target. In the case of the workflow you shared, when a task spends 10 seconds in theRealqueue and then times out, it also times out of the voicemail queue because that was also 10 seconds.

Try setting the voicemail queue target to a bigger timeout than theRealqueue.

```
        "targets": [
          {
            "queue": "theRealqueue",
            "timeout": 10
          },
          {
            "queue": "voicemail",
            "timeout": 20
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Hi please look over my solution. It does not seem to work in the way you mentioned. 
I did try it like that.